# Unclear issue with Promises resolution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

I'm implementing a feature to select and download multiple documents.

First, I build an array of of objects containing each selected document's name and a link to its location.

```
    getAllSelectedUrls = () => {
      const { selectedFiles } = this.state;

      const urls = [];
      selectedFiles.forEach((file) => {
        this.returnFileUrl(file.id).then(res => res.json()).then((data) => {
          urls.push({ fileName: file.name, url: data.content_path });
        });
      });
      return urls;
    }
```

`returnFileUrl()` is an asynchronous API call to obtain a file's link by ID:

```
returnFileUrl = async (fileId) => {
      try {
        const resp = await fetch(`/file?fileId=${fileId}`);
        return resp;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

I thought by updating the `urls` array within the `.then` method, I'd ensure that each `url` would be resolved by the time it returns.

When I call `getAllSelectedUrls()`, I can log the array in the console with all data populated. However, I am unable to iterate over it or access any object by index, presumably because the data hasn't resolved at that point.

Comment: Yes, the `data.content_path` is resolved just fine by the time you push it to the array. But your `getAllSelectedUrls` is not waiting with returning the array until all urls are pushed. Do not use `forEach`, do not use `push`, use `Promise.all` instead and make `getAllSelectedUrls` return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Promise.all()

```
getAllSelectedUrls = () => {
      const { selectedFiles } = this.state;
      return Promise.all(selectedFiles.map(file => {
        return this.returnFileUrl(file.id)
               .then(res => res.json())
               .then(data => ({ fileName: file.name, url: data.content_path }))
      }))
      .then(urls => {

       //do whatever you need to do with the urls array

      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you and @Bergi very much for the help :) Makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Bergi, `return` does not wait until the async call is done. It immediately returns an empty array.
However you could check with every resolve if `urls` array is filled completely. If so - store the variable somewhere, using e.g. `setState`.

Or just move `urls` array into the state and with every resolve simply push `url` to state.

```
selectedFiles.forEach((file) => {
   this.returnFileUrl(file.id).then(res => res.json()).then((data) => {
      urls.push({ fileName: file.name, url: data.content_path });

      if (urls.length === selectedFiles.length) {
         this.setState({ urls });
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(Edited)

```js
    getAllSelectedUrls = async () => {
      const { selectedFiles } = this.state;

      const urls = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
          const file = selectedFiles[i];
          res = await this.returnFileUrl(file.id);
          data = await res.json();
          urls.push({ fileName: file.name, url: data.content_path });
      }

      return urls;
    }
```

Like this, the function will return after all promises are resolved and url pushed

Comment: No, that function will return *before* any url is pushed.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I think I corrected it, what do you think ? @Bergi